# strace tmux output redirected to a file

Tags: io-redirection, strace

I want to check which files does tmux touch when it is launched (not just the list of open files when tmux is running). Strace tmux seemed like the best option.

When trying to redirect the output to a file `strace tmux > /tmp/blah`. File is empty.

Why does this happen? 
How to redirect the trace to a file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Oh I got it. Strace doesn't print to stdout. It prints to stderr.

`strace tmux 2> /tmp/blah` works.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the `-o` option with `strace` which writes the trace output to the file rather than to `stderr`.

`strace -o /tmp/blah tmux`